# Table "SPRING_SESSION" not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

I'm trying to create a REST API using Spring and I've been running into this issue when attempting to implement session handling.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION
WHERE MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL < (? - LAST_ACCESS_TIME) / 1000]; nested
exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SPRING_SESSION" not
found; SQL statement: DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE
MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL < (? - LAST_ACCESS_TIME) / 1000 [42102-195]   at
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]...
```

It looks like Spring thinks that the table doesn't exist, which is confusing me because I've checked the table does exist in the database. I've included `org.springframework.session` in my pom.xml and I've also tried manually creating the table on each start of the application. So far no change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:h2:~/test","sa","password"` OR `jdbc:h2:file:~/test;USER=sa;PASSWORD=password`

try any of these connection strings in your code.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. I'm still new to Spring but I added this via `spring.datasource.url` in the `application.properties` file. Still getting the same error after trying both variants.